# Vincular ID Autoincremental antes de SaveChanges

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Les armo un ejemplo

Tengo dos tablas

**CIERRE**

```
CierreID
Descripcion
```

**Entidad**

```
EntidadID
CierreID
Descripcion
```

A nivel codigo creo un objeto Cierre

```
Cierre a = new Cierre()

a.Descripcion = "Ejemplo"

db.Cierres.Add(a);
```

Ahora yo quiero asignar a entidad este cierre id que todavia no se guardo en base de datos sin hacer un savechanges antes.

Existe alguna manera??

Saludos.

Comment: A ver si entendi. A la clase `Entidad` quieres asignarle el identity asignado de la clase `CIERRE` sin necesidad de hacer SaveChanges()?

Comment: Justo encontre la solucion gracias

Comment: Puedes compartirlas con nosotros? Admito que hasta yo tengo curiosidad.

Comment: si ahi lo estaba agregando a la pregunta. Es una pavada yo no sabia que entity lo realizaba solo. Supongo que ve que los modelos estan relacionados y lo asigna solo.

Comment: Me alegro que encontraras la solución. En lugar de editar la pregunta y añadirla ahi, es mejor que añadas tu propia respuesta. En 48h podrás marcarla como aceptada. Un saludo.

Comment: No sabia lo voy a empezar a hacer asi gracias!!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucion:

```
db.Cierres.Add(a);

foreach (var item in lstEntidades)
{
db.Entidades.Add(item);
}

db.SaveChanges();
```

Entity lo detecta solo.

Espero que les sirva.

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo hago de estas maneras.

**1:**

```
var cierre = db.Cierres.Add(a); // Maestra de cierre

foreach (var item in lstEntidades)
{
     var entidadCierre = new Entidad(){
         EntidadID = item.Id,
         CierreID = cierre.Id
         Descripcion = item.Descripcion
     }
    db.Entidades.Add(entidadCierre);
}

db.SaveChanges();
```

**2:**
**Uso este método para agregar y retornar el Id Insertado**

```
public async Task<int> AddCierre(Cierre newCierre)
{
   try
     {
       var cierre = _context.Cierres.Add(newCierre);
       await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
       return cierre.Id;
     }
   catch (Exception ex)
     {
        throw ex;
     }
}
```

**Controlador**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Nuevo(RolViewModel model)
{
    var newCierre = new Cierre(); // Armar según tu necesidad
    int cierreId = await AddCierre(newCierre); // Id retornado solo quedaría insertar las relaciones con este Id

    using (var db = new DbContext())
    {
       foreach (var item in lstEntidades)
       {
           var entidadCierre = new Entidad(){
              EntidadID = item.Id,
              CierreID = cierreId,
              Descripcion = item.Descripcion
           }
           db.Entidades.Add(entidadCierre);
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
     }
}
```

Espero les sirva